# Who can explain this formula for Stein's Unbiased Risk Estimate to me?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Please can any one explain this formula to me, because I don't have enough information about statistic.

[image]

where d is the length of the signal.

This equation represents Stein's Unbiased Risk Estimate. I don't have any information about symbol such as # or ^.

Comment: The symbol # refers to the number of something. You might like to think of it as a summation with an indicator variable. The second symbol is the wedge which signifies logical conjuction.

Comment: I'm thinking ^ means minimum

Comment: I think that ^ here mean minimum because we don't have logical functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this question is posted long ago, I feel like I should answer it since I was struggling to make sense of it for a while last night.

SURE as you mentioned represent Stein's Unbiased Risk Estimate:

In the equation, there are 3 parts:

The first part is d which as mentioned in the paper is the dimension of data and if we are talking about time-series data, the dimension is effective the length of data(which OP already pointed out)

The second part is 2.#{i: |x(i)| <= t} is simply 2 times the number of elements that is smaller or equal to t. In python, np.sum((np.abs(y)<=t)).

The third part is simply saying do a min check for every element in y which is min(abs(y(i)),t). Then square this result and sum it up.

Technically, you should choose the value of t which produces the smallest SURE.

Answer (score 1):

[Stein's unbiased risk estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_unbiased_risk_estimate) is more general than the SURE estimator you have described. The SURE Shrink estimator is due to [Donoho and Johnstone 1994](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~imj/WEBLIST/1995/ausws.pdf) for wavelet-based denoising and represents a particular application of Stein's result. You can see how it is derived from Stein's result on Page 8 of their paper.

If you are just looking how to interpret the risk of the SURE Shrink estimator, note that d is the dimensionality of the vector, $\#\{i: |x_i| \leq t \}$ just counts the number of elements in the vector whose magnitude is less than the threshold $t$. As for $x \wedge t$, it shrinks x towards 0 by up to a magnitude of $t$. Thus
$$
5 \wedge 2=3\\
-5 \wedge 2=-3\\
-1 \wedge 2 = 0
$$
The actual estimator is the so-called soft thresholding estimator $x \wedge t^S$ in which $$t^S = \arg \min_t SURE(t; x)$$ to the value which minimizes the estimate of risk above.

Comment: Thank you very much that is truly a good explain for my question